# ode formation when constant appears with arc length.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to form ode and solve for

$$ s( 4-s) = y^2+5 $$

where $s$ is arc length of a curve in x-y plane ? The constant 5 disappears when derivating.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition can be written as

$$1+y^2=-(s-2)^2$$

which is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Add an arbitrary arc length $\lambda s $

$$ s^2-4 s + y^2 + 5 + \lambda s =0$$

Differentiate  w.r.t. arc s, $ \sin \phi =\frac{dy}{ds} $ the curvature $ \phi'$

$$ 2s-4 +2y \sin \phi + \lambda =0,\,$$
Differentiate again,

$$ 2+ 2( \sin^2\phi +y \cos \phi \;\phi^{'})=0 $$

simplifies to

$$ \phi^{'}(s)=\dfrac{\cos \phi-1/\cos \phi}{y}$$

which can be numerically integrated using suitably chosen IC. Product of two arc segments depends on $t$ as required.